# Compare future date with current date SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button(action: {
            let soon = Date().addingTimeInterval(100)

            if(soon == Date()) {
                print("Time is up!")
            }
        }) {
            Text("Alert")
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to add some time to soon and then when the current time is == to soon, then execute the print, how can I do that?

What I want is: I have current time, then I add some seconds to that time and when that time is up do something, I need Date() because I'll be working with specific times, for example, if it's 10am, I want to add 3 min, then when it's 10:03am display alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to create an `onReceive` and then do the check there:

```
.onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
    if(self.now > dateInTime) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Then on the actual view I can check if "overdue" then do whatever I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to below code, hope it help you.

On `Button` click you can assign new Date as per your requirement.

```
class TimeCounter: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timerEnd = false
    var timer : Timer?

    var nextDate : Date? = nil {
        didSet {
            if let date = self.nextDate {
                let interval = Date().distance(to: date)
                if self.timer == nil {
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: false) {_ in
                        self.timerEnd = true
                        self.timer = nil
                        self.nextDate = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var timeCounter = TimeCounter()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { //change as per requirement
            self.timeCounter.nextDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(10) 
        }) {
            Text("Display alert after 10 seconds")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: .constant(self.timeCounter.timerEnd)) {
            return Alert(title: Text("Alert"), message: Text("Alert after updated date") , dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("OK"), action: {
                self.timeCounter.timerEnd = false
            }))
        }
    }
}
```